# Why isn't context missed when I pass callback in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
  data: () => ({
    showCurrenciesPopup: false,
  }),
  methods: {
    closeCurrenciesPopup() {
      this.showCurrenciesPopup = false;
    },
    escapeKeyListener(event: any) {
      if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        this.closeCurrenciesPopup();
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.escapeKeyListener);
  },
```

seems context should be lost here `document.addEventListener('keyup', this.escapeKeyListener)`, but not! No any errors, everything works. Does somebody know what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use bind methods of Function
just like this:

```
created() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.escapeKeyListener.bind(this));
},
```

[image]

[image]

these are source code of vue, do you understand?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Can you explain this further @RodionGolovushkin ? I agree with jacky that this is the answer.

Comment: methods which your defined in methods will be substituted with fn.bind(vm)

Comment: @ThomasKleßen jacky has updated his answer since my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Vue they attempt to adopt a similar approach than callback auto-bound to the element in traditional `addEventListener`:

> If attaching a handler function to an element using addEventListener(), the value of `this` inside the handler is a reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the currentTarget property of the event argument that is passed to the handler.

Extract of the section called "The value of this within the handler" on MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Except in the case of Vue, they bend the rule a little, it's not auto-bound to the element (`document` in your example) but the component.